# Return Arabic text via ASP.NET JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, arabic

I want to return Arabic text via asp.net web-method returned as JSON, 
This is code I'm using:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void getAr()
{
    ResultTemplate resultTemplate = new ResultTemplate();
    resultTemplate.data = "بسم الله";

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string retJSON = js.Serialize(resultTemplate);

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", retJSON.Length.ToString());
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(retJSON);
}
```

When I run the web-method it keeps loading without any response!

Comment: try changing your status to static, and return the variable retJSON instead of using Context.

Comment: please show how you are calling this webmethod.

Comment: @Quannt what status ! and if i return return the variable retJSON it will return as XML no JSON as i need

Comment: @naveen i just call it from browser: 
http://localhost:1959/req/ArabicTest.asmx/getAr

Comment: i see no problem with your code. it works on my browser. could you change the first two lines to `string resultTemplate = "بسم الله";` and tell me if you see anything in your browser?

Comment: still loading with no response received, i'm using firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `WebMethod` like this. Change its signature to:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getAr()
{
  string result;
  // fill it ...
  return result;
}
```

Plus

`Response.Flush` means send the buffered output immediately. so you should put it at the end.

```
Context.Response.Write(retJSON);
Context.Response.Flush();
```

Also `content-length` is not equal to the string.Length. You should convert it to an array of bytes and then use its length.

```
byte[] s = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultString);
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", s.Length.ToString());
response.BinaryWrite(s);
```